# NodeJS Socket.IO Wont Connect

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io, iisnode

I built an online chat application using NodeJS, Express, and Socket.IO - runs fine locally, but cant get it working on the server.  I'm running Windows 2012/IIS 8.5/IISNode.  My site is not running as a virtual, it's running as an application in this format: http://[domainname]/subfolder/chatserver.js.

When I run the app, I have a route setup so if you go to '/', it serves up a regular html chat window.  If you go to a second url, it serves up an admin chat window.  Both windows should connect to the server in order to send out messages, however I cant get it to connect.

I'm referencing the socketio client like so:

```
<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.7/socket.io.min.js">    </script>
```

When I run it locally, I actually dont have to reference it like this, I can do this instead

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This way, if I understand correctly, it should download the script from the server.  However, I get 404 no matter what I try using this method.

In the client code, I'm executing this call: 
    socket = io.connect(address, details);
    console.log(socket);

After the connect method, the socket.connected is false.  Does anyone know if it's not connecting because I'm downloading the js from a different location than the nodejs app running on the server?

My second question is, why wouldnt I be able to reference the script properly and have it automatically downloaded?  Is it because I'm running as an application, not as a virtual?  I need to be able to run as an application so that I can use the domain name.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been working through this problem for going on 4 days now! :(

Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the server-faye.js and server-socketio.js files are node.js applications 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="chatserver.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- indicate that all strafic the URL paths beginning with 'socket.io' should be 
    redirected to the server-socketio.js node.js application to avoid IIS attempting to 
    serve that content using other handlers (e.g. static file handlers)
    -->

    <rewrite>
         <rules>
              <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                   <match url="socket.io" />
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="chatserver.js" />
              </rule>
         </rules>
    </rewrite>    

    <!-- disable the IIS websocket module to allow node.js to provide its own 
    WebSocket implementation -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat-index.html');
});

app.get('/chat-admin', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat-admin.html');
});

httpServer.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on port: ' + port);
});

// Fires when a client connects to the server
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

As you can see it's very basic.  When I hit the url, I should get two messages.  The first saying it's listening on a port, and the second saying a user connected.  Locally, I get both.  On the server, I just get the listening on a port message.

Here's the client code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body class="chat-body">

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Connect to the chat server
            socket = io();
            console.log(socket.connected);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script tag (note the slightly different leading slash from what you have):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

will work if you have a web server that will serve up `socket.io.js` when it receives a request for this path.

If you are running node.js server-side and initializing the socket.io library properly on node.js and you have socket.io installed properly on the server, then socket.io will intercept that above request and will serve `socket.io.js` back to the browser.  Since you're getting a 404, you apparently don't have this configured correctly.  Since you haven't provided any of your node.js code, we can't really advise any more specifically.

Comment: I've finally narrowed this down a bit.  I setup the dante example as a virtual in IIS.  I then setup a site called dante.com pointed to the exact same folder as the virtual and added a host entry.  The virtual folder works, the site doesnt.  The diff is when i hit the virtual folder url it makes this call: http://localhost/dante/socket.io/socket.io.js which returns the js.  Calling dante.com makes the same call like: http://dante.com/socket.io/socket.io.js and returns the client.html, not the js.  The rewrite must be what's causing the issue somehow but I cant see anything wrong with it.